# Sum values from dynamic inputs created in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function (it works) to create a number of dynamic inputs:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

 var arr = []; 

 function espacioArreglos() {
 // Number of inputs to create
        var number = document.getElementById("cantidadArreglos").value;
        // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        // Clear previous contents of the container
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            // Append a node with a random text
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Arreglo #" + (i+1)));
            // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "number";
            input.name = "arreglo" + i;

  //set ID to each input to calculate summatory
          var inputId = 'input-' + i;
          input.setAttribute('id', inputId);
          arr.push(inputId);
          input.setAttribute('onchange', function() {
var sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function(val) {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById(val).value;
    if (inputVal) sum += inputVal;
});


document.getElementById('totalPlacas').value = sum;
});
            container.appendChild(input);
            // Append a line break 
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));


 }
 }

 </script>
```

And now I want to display the sum of the input values. Here is the HTML:

```
 <tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Cantidad de arreglos:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="number" id="cantidadArreglos" onchange="espacioArreglos();" size="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Cantidad de placas:</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><div id="container"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Total de placas:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><div id="totalPlacas"></div></td>
</tr>
```

So, you enter a number in "Cantidad de arreglos", it calls the function "espacioArreglos" and then I want to use the values that I will enter on the generated inputs to calculate its summatory, which should be displayed at the div "totalPlacas". However, nothing appears... Whats the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes that need to be done:

First, change the 
`<div id="container"/>` to `<div id="container"></div>` as the shortcut on a div breaks the HTML causing that totalPlacas doesn't exists.

Second, add the onchange event using

```
input.onchange = function() {...}
```

Now the result should be added to the 'totalPlacas' div using .innerText = sum instead using the .value = sum.

Now you can check that the result displayed is a concatenation of strings instead adding the numbers, this can be solved replacing

```
if (inputVal) sum += inputVal;
```

with

```
if (inputVal) sum += parseInt(inputVal);
```

You should add some kind of validation to avoid an error when the user types a letter or symbol instead a number.

Hope it works!

Comment: Finally it works perfectly!! But its .value that I needed to add, not .innerText :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign a unique ID to the input elements, so you can reference them using `document.getElementById()`.

Something like:

```
input.setAttribute("id", 'input' + i);
```

Comment: But how can I display the result on the id "totalPlacas"? Should I change the command "onchange"?

Comment: totalPlacas is a div, so it doesn't have the value property to display the result.
You can use document.getElementById('totalPlacas').innerHTML = totalSum; to display it

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning id's to the dynamic inputs and storing them in an array. First, outside of the function (global scope) define an empty array:

```
var arr = [];
```

In your for loop:

```
var inputId = 'input-' + i;
input.setAttribute('id', inputId);
arr.push(inputId);
input.setAttribute('onchange', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(val) {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById(val).value;
        if (inputVal) sum += inputVal;
    });

    // do something with the sum
    console.log(sum)
});
```

Comment: But how can I display the value on the id "totalPlacas"?

Comment: document.getElementById('totalPlacas').value = sum; You could use this in the onchange event of the dynamic inputs. Each time the user changes the number in one of the inputs the sum would update in totalPlacas.

Comment: nothing happens... Here's the thing: I don't think the function "sumPlacas" is being trigered. The row is "readonly", so it would never change. And if I use a "div", I can't use "onchange"... Can you recommend me something else please?

Comment: Check the edit. You don't need the sumPlacas onchange event as you mentioned that it's a readonly input anyhow.

Comment: Thank you :) But I don't understand where you want to close your "input.setAttribute('onchange', function() " ...

Comment: Sorry my bad I didn't close that properly. The second argument to setAttribute is the function that we want to sum the numbers. You could also define the function somewhere else and reference it like input.setAttribute('onchange', nameOfSummingFunction);

Comment: I would change the readonly input to a div with a p or h tag. <p id="totalPlacas"></p>  document.getElementById('totalPlacas').innerHTML = sum;

Comment: Still nothing is displayed... Should I edit something more in the JS code?!